# Generate multiple lattice plots on a grid using lapply in R

Tags: r, plot, grid-layout, lattice, lapply

How do plot multiple lattice plots onto a single lattice plot where the plots are generated using an lapply function?

The following is a demonstration of what I have tried so far using the built in `mtcars` dataset.

```
require(lattice)

response <- c("cyl","disp","hp","drat")

par(mfrow=c(2,2))

lapply(response, function(variable) {
  print(xyplot(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars[variable]))
})
```

This produces the plots desired. However it seems to be ignoring the `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` instruction and plotting each plot separately.

Comment: `lapply` is designed to iterate over a list applying a function, where each return value is used as an entry in a returned list.  If you aren't returning a value, `for` is more appropriate.

Comment: Yes. `grid` plotting functions do ignore `par(mfrow=.)`. Read the help page for `?Lattice` more carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really don't want to use the built-in facetting or viewport options of lattice, you can replicate the behavior of `par(mfrow)` with the following,

```
require(lattice)

response <- c("cyl","disp","hp","drat")

# save all plots in a list
pl <- lapply(response, function(variable) {
  xyplot(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars[variable])
})

library(gridExtra)
# arrange them in a 2x2 grid
do.call(grid.arrange, c(pl, nrow=2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not how `lattice` is intended to be used (`grid` would be more appropriate).

Here is a `lattice` solution:

```
xyplot(mpg ~ cyl+disp+hp+drat,
       data=mtcars,
       groups=cyl+disp+hp+drat,
       scales=list(relation="free"),
       col="blue"
)
```

[image]

Comment: I realise that I am not using lattice to its full capability. However, the actual function I am using for plotting is very complex and the built in faceted graphics capabilities in lattice is insufficient for my purpose. The grid package, however, does solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The multiplot function on [this page](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/) is something I have used many times to get multiple plot objects on one page.