# Downsampling dataset

Tags: r, subsampling

I have a dataset, which is a large character vector (1,024,459 elements), consisting of gene IDs. It looks like:

```
> length(allres)
[1] 1024459
>allres[1:10]  
[1] "1"   "1"   "1"   "1"   "1"   "1"   "1"   "10"  "10"  "100"
```

where each gene ID is repeated the number of times it was seen in an RNA seq run (so here, there were 7 reads for gene "1", 2 for gene "10"). I want to plot the number of genes identified per number of reads, at 10,000 read intervals, so that I can see how many genes are identified if I randomly sample 10,000 reads, 20,000, 30,0000, etc. I made a spacing vector with the seq() function like so:

```
> gaps <- seq(10000, length(allres), by=10000)
```

but I'm unsure how to apply that to my allres vector and plot it. Any help is quite appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you probably want is something like this:

```
gaps <- seq(10000, length(allres), by = 10000)

lapply(gaps, function(x){

    #This will give you the number of appearances of each value, within
    #an gaps[x]-sized sample of allres
    aggregated_sample <- table(sample(allres, size = x))

    #plotting code for sample goes here. And "x" is the number of reads so
    #you can even use it in the title!
    #Just remember to include code to save it to disc, if you want to save it to disc.
    return(TRUE)

})
```

If you're using ggplot2 for plotting, of course, you can even save the plot as an object and then return(plot) instead of return(TRUE) and do further tweakery/investigation afterwards.

Comment: That's definitely doing what I want, thanks! I'm still trying to figure out how to get everything on one single plot. I've tried a couple things, along the lines of "plot(x, xlab="reads", ylab="genes")", but this results in a separate graph for every data point.

Comment: That is, every datapoint within one instance of "gaps", or do you want all the "gaps" options on one plot?

Comment: All the gaps options on one plot would be best.

Comment: Okay, then you want to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641891/generate-multiple-lattice-plots-on-a-grid-using-lapply-in-r).

Comment: Thanks! Still took me a bit to put it all together correctly, but that definitely pointed me in the right direction. :-)